# What are the disadvantages of implementing transactions away from the database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions

We know that there are some scenarios that require us to implement transactions in code, such as `SqlTransaction`/`TransactionScope` in .Net framework. The questions are:

1. What are the overheads (besides
   speed)?
2. Does it gets worse if we add more
   layers between the transaction and
   the DB? If yes, then what are the
   overheads and what cause these
   overheads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to keep transactions short, to begin them as late as possible and to end them as early as possible. Otherwise concurrency hurts, and we are getting more lock waiting and deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Long running transaction can also cause transaction log to fill.

Adding more layers between transaction and DB itself doesn't add overhead on the transaction but it will increase the probability of something going wrong and leaving transaction uncommitted and long running transaction.

Comment: Which layers are you referring to, and how would that increase the likelihood of something going wrong?